GradCam returns different results for each approach
I want to understand what my CNN model is focusing on. I've read that analyzing the last layer can help, but each method I've used to generate Grad-CAM shows different results. These often suggest that the model is focusing on what seems to be irrelevant areas, though I might be mistaken, as I'm not a medical expert.
Here is my model:
def build_model():
    input_img = Input(shape=(224,224,3), name='ImageInput')
    x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv1_1')(input_img)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv1_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='pool1')(x)
    
    x = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv2_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv2_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='pool2')(x)
    
    x = SeparableConv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv3_1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
    x = SeparableConv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv3_2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name='bn2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='pool3')(x)
    
    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.7, name='dropout1')(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5, name='dropout2')(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc3')(x)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x)
    return model

custom_model =  build_model()

This is the test data generator:
train_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'  
)

The first approach: - source
# Build the model
custom_model = build_model()

# Load the weights into the model
custom_model.load_weights('best_model_todate.weights.h5')

# Set the model to inference mode if necessary
custom_model.trainable = False

model_builder = custom_model

img_size = (224, 224)
preprocess_input = train_data_gen
#decode_predictions = custom_model.predict(test_data_gen)
decode_predictions = y_pred

last_conv_layer_name = "Conv3_2"

# The local path to our target image

directory = "MERGED_ALL_CLEAN_balanced_ready/test/PNEUMONIA/"

# List all image files in the directory
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]

# Choose a random file and construct the full path in one line
img_path = f"{directory}{random.choice(files)}"
print(img_path)

#img_path = "MERGED_ALL_CLEAN_balanced_ready/test/NORMAL/NORMAL(13812).jpeg"


display(Image(img_path))


def get_img_array(img_path, size):
    # `img` is a PIL image of size 299x299
    img = keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
    # `array` is a float32 Numpy array of shape (299, 299, 3)
    array = keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    # We add a dimension to transform our array into a "batch"
    # of size (1, 299, 299, 3)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
    return array


def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activationsget_img
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = keras.models.Model(
        model.inputs, [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array, training = False)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()


from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input

# Prepare image
img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=img_size))

# Make model
model = model_builder  # No need to reload weights here since they were already loaded
# Remove last layer's softmax
model.layers[-1].activation = None

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name)

# Display heatmap
#plt.matshow(heatmap)
#plt.show()

def save_and_display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap, cam_path="cam.jpg", alpha=0.4):
    # Load the original image
    img = keras.utils.load_img(img_path)
    img = keras.utils.img_to_array(img)

    # Rescale heatmap to a range 0-255
    heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)

    # Use jet colormap to colorize heatmap
    jet = mpl.colormaps["jet"]

    # Use RGB values of the colormap
    jet_colors = jet(np.arange(256))[:, :3]
    jet_heatmap = jet_colors[heatmap]

    # Create an image with RGB colorized heatmap
    jet_heatmap = keras.utils.array_to_img(jet_heatmap)
    jet_heatmap = jet_heatmap.resize((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
    jet_heatmap = keras.utils.img_to_array(jet_heatmap)

    # Superimpose the heatmap on original image
    superimposed_img = jet_heatmap * alpha + img
    superimposed_img = keras.utils.array_to_img(superimposed_img)

    # Save the superimposed image
    superimposed_img.save(cam_path)
    

    # Display Grad CAM
    display(Image(cam_path))


save_and_display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap)

Second approach: - source
img = preprocess_image(img_path)
heatmap = grad_cam(custom_model, img, layer_name='Conv3_2', label_name=None, category_id=None)
show_imgwithheat(img_path, heatmap)

third approach: - source
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tf_explain.core import GradCAM


img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = preprocess_input(img_array)
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)


explainer = GradCAM()
heatmap = explainer.explain(
    (img_array, None),
    custom_model,
    class_index=0,  
    layer_name='Conv3_2'  
)

plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()

Those are the original pictures and results of all 3 approaches in order:



I don't really understand why all 3 approaches yield completely different results also i believe the hotspots are irrelevant to the task (classifying heatlhy and pneumonia lungs) yet the model has quite high accuracy on test na validation sets.

test_loss, test_acc, test_auc, test_precision, test_recall = custom_model.evaluate(test_data_gen)

print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_acc:.4f}")
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
print(f"Test AUC: {test_auc:.4f}")
print(f"Test Precision: {test_precision:.4f}")
print(f"Test Recall: {test_recall:.4f}")

val_loss, val_acc, val_auc, val_precision, val_recall = custom_model.evaluate(valid_data_gen)

print(f"Val Accuracy: {val_acc:.4f}")
print(f"Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}")
print(f"Val AUC: {val_auc:.4f}")
print(f"Val Precision: {val_precision:.4f}")
print(f"Val Recall: {val_recall:.4f}")

Metrics evaluation for both sets test and validation.
Test Accuracy: 0.9570
Test Loss: 0.1253
Test AUC: 0.9896
Test Precision: 0.9719
Test Recall: 0.9412

Val Accuracy: 0.9425
Val Loss: 0.1464
Val AUC: 0.9869
Val Precision: 0.9557
Val Recall: 0.9279

the weights got saved on 15 epoch as the ModelCheckpoint found it was the best.

For starters, (1) and (2) are simply different algorithms, just very similar. Different results are to be expected. The only difference to (1) I found in (3) is that they only use positive gradients before the pooling step by default. Why the image in (3) looks so weird, I hae no idea. Also, did you check if the prediction of the model for that image is correct? Otherwise you get the heatmap for another class.

For the interpretability, I only have a speculative take. Take a look at this notbook. In it, the author explains that "The activations of layers higher-up carry less and less information about the specific input being seen, and more and more information about the target". In your case it could be that because you have so many dense layers following, and only 6 conv layers, that the information at the last conv layer is only "halfway" to the target stage.
